# How to splice an element from an array in angular 7 without disturbing the main array

Tags: angular

My [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acmc4d) (Please bare with my UI. I have created it just to understand the concept)

When I choose 'Select all' and then start deselecting A,B,... , the elements are getting spliced from the mainList. But in my typescript file I have spliced the element only from the filteredList and not from my mainList. Kindly explain how removing an element from the filteredList also removes it from mainList. Am I doing anything wrong here? Or If this is the functionality which could not be changed, how could I reserve my mainList without getting sliced.

I have checked with below links. But they didn't work

- [Cloning an array in Javascript/Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808882/cloning-an-array-in-javascript-typescript/54138394)
- [Copy array of Objects in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573579/copy-array-of-objects-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are assigning `this.mainList` to `this.filteredList` you are copying the *reference*. So any actions you perform on one list will affect the other.

Instead you should take a copy of the array by using `slice`.

```js
this.filteredList=this.mainList.slice();
```

Note - the object references inside the arrays are still the same - so any actions you perform on the inner objects will be reflected in both lists.

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = arr1;

arr2[1] = 4;

console.log('update reference');
console.log(arr1, arr2);

const arr3 = arr1.slice();
arr3[1] = 2;

console.log('update slice');
console.log(arr1, arr3);
```

EDIT

While this is one part of your issue, you are still copying your main array reference in other parts of your code.

I would recommend starting again with a different approach. Here's my very simplified version, albeit without "Select All" functionality: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ihkbfn

Comment: Looking at your stackblitz in more detail, I think you have other issues. I've simplified your example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ihkbfn. I removed the "Select all" functionality, but that should be simple enough to add back in

Answer (score 1):

**`this.filteredList = this.mainList.map(ele=>{return ele});`**

after this perform all the operation on filteredlist as this will make a deep copy of the array

Comment: This works because it is the same concept as a slice, just a bit more verbose

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the `Spread Operator` in TypeScript, I think that will solve your issue.

In TypeScript, the spread operator (in form of ellipsis) can be used to initialize arrays and objects from another array or object. You can also use spread operator for object destructuring.

Just one example, Initialize arrays another array and then slice that new itilialized array

**Initialize arrays another array**

You can use spread operator to create arrays from existing arrays in given fashion.

```
let origArrayOne = [ 1, 2, 3];                          //1,2,3
let origArrayTwo = [ 4, 5, 6];                          //4,5,6

//Create new array from existing array
let copyArray = [...origArrayOne];                      //1,2,3

//Create new array from existing array + more elements
let newArray `enter code here`= [...origArrayOne, 7, 8];             //1,2,3,7,8 

//Create array by merging two arrays
let mergedArray = [...origArrayOne, ...origArrayTwo];   //1,2,3,4,5,6
```